# Should we add Software Recommendations as a migration target?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

An inclusion of [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) in the migration links:

[image]

Comment: Possible //TO DO at a later date http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd probably be against making the change to the off-topic reason as you describe, but I do think it's a good idea to revisit adding SR to the migration list. We're much larger than the last time we had this discussion, and more capable of handling the extra volume.

Comment: Types of Questions on topic for SW rec http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How many questions can you find that would be acceptable there as-is? What percentage of all closed-as-recommendation questions is that?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm not sure how to determine an exact number on that, but I know, as a active participant of the http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers# that I see questions that would be suitable. I can have a look and report back with this.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221970/179419. **tl;dr** There's never a migration path to beta sites and the SO community has demonstrated its inability to migrate over the years, and there's a danger we'd swallow SR whole. _They_ get to decide, not SO.

Comment: There have been 0 migrations to SR and one migration from SR to SO in the past 90 days.

Comment: @Ben yes I understand. I was chatting with Undo about it from [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28379258#28379258) and am wondering if it's a good idea.

Comment: @Ben That answer was from nearly two years ago - SR has grown, and I do think it's a good idea to look at this from a fresh perspective. Not saying we should run in blindly and do it, but a lot has changed since I wrote that answer.

Comment: Also, I'd disagree with this being a duplicate of the other question - they're from two different eras, fresh discussion is good.

Comment: @Ben besides, SR is out of Beta for a while now ;) What I am concerned about personally is users who "think" it belongs there without "knowing" (i.e. "sounds like a goot fit by the name"). At SR, we have a set of strong guidelines what a question must contain and what it should not be about. I remember well the discussion we had on Android.SE chat (and later TL) on this topic: even mods are affected by that attitude ("by name seems to be a good match, let them sort out the rest"), which gave quite a little uproar on that end.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is good to keep an open mind about how we, as a community, can direct quality questions to the right audience. If it is within Stack Overflow we need to correctly tag questions, if we know there is a more suitable community within the Stack Exchange it is our duty also to bring such questions to their attention.

For any visitors that arrive here let me re-iterate the golden rule of migration: don't migrate crap. I'm not saying your proposal is suggesting to do that but it turns out over the years that <s>crap</s> what is on-topic is defined differently in each community. That makes migration hard for non-regulars and a frustration for the receiving end.

In the similar proposals to add or change that list I must yet find one where every community is happy with. There isn't much real-estate in that dialog, so UX minded users cringe by the idea of adding more choices, or needing more clicks/keyboard actions to select a site. It is a though subject....and I don't have a solution for that... sorry.

With that out of the way, let's look at the merits of replacing one of the options or adding Software Recommendations to that list.

I'm somewhat obsessed with numbers and queries so I re-used [a query I wrote for an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247902/158100) on MSE and reformed that to [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/428377).

Let me explain a bit what we can get from the public data in SEDE. The [posthistory table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) holds migration records for *away* and *here*. After a successful migration the migration stub is removed after 30 days. So any away records that are still available in that table or for rejected migrations. The receiving site gets an [*here*](https://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/428374/software-recommendations) entry and that one stays in the table.

As you can see from that result based only on the numbers there are a lot more sites that have received questions from Stack Overflow that are also not on the migration dialog. Based on this I would say that Software Recommendations is not yet a candidate to be on the migration dialog.

If the statistics are not helping to support the request maybe there are different motivations possible. One argument could be that the migration target is in trouble getting quality question or a healthy community. Having a bigger group of users help out in getting good question to such sites might be a way to grow the SE network as a whole. I can't judge if SR needs this treatment now or if they needed it earlier on but I understand from the comments that the site is out of beta which is an indication of how they are doing.

Based on what I know now I don't think SR needs to be added. But if this meta question can be featured on the meta of Software Recommendations maybe that community sees it different and be pleased and welcoming if we migrate questions that are on-topic for them. If that gets a positive feedback I will reconsider.

For now I say we don't add Software Recommendations to the migration dialog.

Comment: Stack Overflow has [a few dozen software recommendations that haven't been closed yet](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+intitle%3A%22best%22+intitle%3A%22(library%7CIDE)%22+-%22marked+as%22+-%22closed+as%22+-site%3Arads.stackoverflow.com). Is it possible that we could migrate them to Software Recommendations instead of closing them?

Comment: Of the 5 or so I checked @AndersonGreen none of those look like they meet the [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), nor are they fixable by the community. I'll not help migrate that as I don't want to annoy the mods there, one of them happens to be a mod here as well. Maybe the site specific chatroom can help in deciding which ones can go and then flag the specific questions for a mod so they can migrate.